# WPF ComboBox items stays in the list after Visibility.Collapsed

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, filtering, visibility

I got a problem with wpf ComboBox. 
I first added a Textbox as the first item to use it for my filtering propose
I then added about 20 Checkboxes in the Combobox through a Foreach loop. 
like this
 [image]

now when i filter them out (i check if true then Visibility.Collapsed) their  trace are still in the Combobox like this [image]

Remember that the items are one by one added to the combobox
 like this

```
DataTable machinesTable = machineModel.GetAllMachines().Tables[0];

List<CheckBox> list = new List<CheckBox>();

foreach (DataRow item in machinesTable.Rows)
{
    string ID = item["ID"].ToString();
    string manufacture = item["MANUFACTURER"].ToString();
    string model = item["MODEL"].ToString();
    MachinesComboBox.Items.Add(new CheckBox() { Uid = ID, Content = manufacture + " - " + model });
}
```

and the filtering system works like this

```
foreach (object item in MachinesComboBox.Items)
{
    if (item is CheckBox)
    {
        if (((CheckBox)item).Content.ToString().Contains(MachinFilterTextbox.Text) || MachinFilterTextbox.Text=="")
        {
            ((CheckBox)item).Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            ((CheckBox)item).Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into the [MVVM design pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx) but as a quick fix you could set the `Visibility` of the parent `ComboBoxItem` container:

```
foreach (CheckBox item in MachinesComboBox.Items.OfType<CheckBox>())
{
    ComboBoxItem container = MachinesComboBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as ComboBoxItem;
    if (item.Content.ToString().Contains(MachinFilterTextbox.Text) || MachinFilterTextbox.Text == "")
    {
        container.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        container.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Knowing that this is kinda of necroing. But I am having the same issue with a legacy application we are using, but the method suggested here does for some reason not work for us as 

ComboBoxItem container = MachinesComboBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as ComboBoxItem;

Always becomes null. Is there another way to access the container easily or is this a larger issue that should be solved higher up?